# sql stored procedures and bitwise operators

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, bitwise-operators

I have a categories table:

```
    id;description;special
    ----------------------
    1;Spares;TRUE
    2;Accessories;TRUE
    4;Consumables;TRUE
    8;Services;TRUE
    11;Printer;FALSE
    12;Monitor;FALSE
    13;Other;FALSE
```

The special field designates special categories that have fixed ids and cannot be deleted nor modified. I've assigned bitwise OR-able ids to those.

Then I have items, each item belongs to a category (with a 1:n relationship).

Now I'd like to write a stored procedure that takes an input parameter containing an OR-ed combination of ids:

```
1 I want spare parts
2 I want accessories
4 I want consumables 
**5 I want consumables AND spare parts**
```

etc

If the parameter is NULL, then I want every item regardless of its category.

This is quite easy, say the parameter is called `_or_category`, then the `WHERE` clause could be something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    items I 
JOIN 
    categories C ON (C.id = I.category)
WHERE
    (_or_category IS NULL) OR (C.special = TRUE AND C.id | _or_categoria = _or_categoria)
;
```

**First problem:**
**edit: sorry this is not a problem, since I have C.special=TRUE in the WHERE clause.**
category 12 could be "seen" as id=8 OR 4, thus if I want to select only the consumables, I would get also the monitors!

**Second problem:**
I don't know how to specify when I want all the items which are NOT a service (cat: 8).

Comment: If you want to bit-wise these, why are you using 11, 12, and 13 as ids?  Shouldn't these be powers of 2?

Comment: I only want to bit-wise the special categories, not all the other.

Comment: If you are using bitwise they need to be mutually exclusive... so you cant have overlapping possibilities. Right now a Printer looks like a service with consumables. You would need 2 bytes to represent this properly. 0x01 - spares to 0x40 Other

Answer (score 1):

> Second problem: I don't know how to
>   specify when I want all the items
>   which are NOT a service (cat: 8)

If I understand your question I think you're looking for the bitwise Invert bits `~`

for example

```
C.special = TRUE AND  (~C.ID | or_categoria = _or_categoria)
```

Comment: that's true, but in the **same** procedure I want to specify, via parameters, all the possible combinations: select all the items, select all the items belonging to one ore more categories, select all the items the don't belong to one ore more categories.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
0x01 - Spares
0x02 - Accessories
0x04 - Consumables
0x08 - Services
0x10 - Printer
0x20 - Monitor
0x40 - Other
```

And all things not services =  `0x7F & ~0x08`

Edit: If you only want the first 4 things to be flags it is not much different. The first 4 bits are reserved exclusively for your bit comparisons. So you cannot have any additional ids that would require a value in the first 4 bits (from the right)...

```
0x01 - Spares
0x02 - Accessories
0x04 - Consumables
0x08 - Services
0x10 - Printer
0x20 - Monitor
0x30 - Other
```

And again, `Ax(~Sx) = 0x3F & ~0x08`

Comment: Thanks but maybe my question wasn't clear enough: the only bit-wiseable categories are the special ones, so that I only need the ids: 1, 2, 4, 8. The other categories are free to use any id > 15.

Comment: Updated, you just cant have id's that use the first 4 bits.